# Javascript multiplying a String value

Tags: javascript

Why when I do this:

```js
console.log('2551.01' * 100);
```

It logs:

```
255101.00000000003
```

But when I do this:

```js
console.log('2551.02' * 100);
```

It works just fine, logging this:

```
255102
```

Comment: Read about floating point.

Comment: Being a string is irrelevant, it's just a floating point arithmetic problem. `console.log(2551.01 * 100)` would produce the same result